# How can I protect IP sensitive computational code so my website programmer cannot decode/read it, but can use it?

Tags: security, web, encryption, obfuscation

I have unique computations that are commercially valuable but I cannot code websites at a pro level, so I want to engage a pro (team) to do it.

How can I protect certain computational code lines so that they can be used in the site, but not decompiled into a readable form by anyone, including the coding team?

I have no preference for the website framework or language, so you choose - please let me know whatever works.

Comment: If you are not a coding pro, how can the language not be relevant? We need to know which languages you are comfortable coding in.

Comment: Hi Mathias. You can make it harder by using obfuscation tools, but you can never prevent someone reverse engineering code. Also asking for recommendations for a tool or framework is off-topic for this site.  See What topics can I ask about here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Why can you not just setup an API service that does the logic and interfaces with the website?

Comment: Thank you guys, sorry if it's off topic (I am a new member). Esp. thanks to you Luke Joshua Park, your answer is a solid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the best way to protect your code is to manage access to it.

Set up an API service that allows your website developer to make requests and receive responses - but not actually have direct access to the logic.